# Hide pictures compression dialog box in VBA (Excel 2010)

Tags: excel, vba, dialog, compression, hide

I use a macro to automatically compress pictures in Excel 2010, the macro opens a dialog and sendkeys, and final users can see it (for half a second), i want to hide it. Please help !

This is my macro:

```
Sub compression()
Application.SendKeys "%w~"
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PicturesCompress"
End Sub
```

I already tried:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

But they don't seem to work.

@TomPreston
Here's my whole code, i want users to double click on type of cells to insert pictures in comments but the pictures must be compressed to keep the file fit !

I ALSO have problems with sendkeys and num lock, if someone can help me on this (see below):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    If Not Intersect(Target, [v:v]) Is Nothing Then

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
             .AllowMultiSelect = False
             .InitialFileName = CurDir
             .Filters.Clear
             .Filters.Add Description:="Images", Extensions:="*.png;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif", Position:=1
             .Title = "Choose image"

             If .Show = -1 Then TheFile = .SelectedItems(1) Else TheFile = 0
        End With

    If TheFile = 0 Then
    MsgBox ("No image selected")
    Exit Sub
    End If

    ActiveCell.ClearComments
    Selection.AddComment
    PreviousCell = ActiveCell.Address
    ActiveCell.Comment.Shape.Fill.UserPicture TheFile

    NumLockState = GetKeyState(VK_NUMLOCK)

    Application.SendKeys "%a~"
    Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PicturesCompress"

    If NumLockState <> GetKeyState(VK_NUMLOCK) Then
    Application.SendKeys ("%{Numlock}"), True
    End If

    ActiveCell.Comment.Visible = True

    CommentAdded = True

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    End If

    End Sub
```

Users can change de size of the picture and after the selection change, the comment is hidden.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If CommentAdded = True Then

Range(PreviousCell).Comment.Visible = False

PreviousCell = ""

CommentAdded = False

End If

End Sub
```

And these are the variables:

```
Public CommentAdded As Boolean
Public PreviousCell As String
Public Const VK_NUMLOCK = &H90
Public Declare Function GetKeyState Lib "user32" _
(ByVal nVirtKey As Long) As Long
```

Comment: If that's the case (you already tried the display alerts etc) we'll need to see the code for the control in question

Comment: @tompreston , i updated the answer ^^

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to hide the flicker effect, use this:

```
Sub compression()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.SendKeys "%w~" Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PicturesCompress"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry i missclicked the posting of the topic, but i already tried it and it doesn't work, the dialog still shows up.